# Excel - Use Variable Cell Value (Sheet1!A2) in From MySQL Database Query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to add a variable value, based on the value of cell A2 in Sheet1 of my Excel Workbook, to the following MySQL Query in the Query Editor:

```
SELECT o.Name, o.OrganizationId

FROM Organization AS o

WHERE o.OrganizationId = Sheet1!A2

ORDER BY o.Name ASC
```

I've tried using a [Customized Parameter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd), but it doesn't seem to work with MySQL queries.

Another thing I've tried running the query through a VBA script:

```
Sub VoucherQuery()
queryString = "SELECT Name, OrganizationId FROM [Vouchers!$A1:B1000000] 
WHERE OrganizationId=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```

But wasn't able to combine this with [a query I looked up](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/other-software-applications/excel-and-or-sql-help/106608-return-sql-query-results-in-a-worksheet-vba-code).

The final attempt had me create a new Workbook and Get Data from Workbook, where I pulled the data from the Workbook with the original SQL Query (same query as above, without the WHERE clause), and tried to add a Condition, but I couldn't find any code to edit with that way of pulling data.

Does anyone know how to achieve this with the Get Data -> From MySQL Database Query Editor in Excel ?

Comment: Hi. First off I am not an Excel user (at the moment) but am familiar somewhat with MySQL. If you 'hard code' your Excel sheet value in the MySQL WHERE clause, do you get any results? Maybe if you do, there is a connectivity issue between MySQL and Excel somewhere? Just tossing out ideas. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @J2112O Sorry for the late reply, read over this comment. It connects fine when I'm running other queries, just not with a variable value from Excel in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Query Editor but this macro should work for you situation.

Would just need to fill in your connection information under the comment `"fill these out below"` and replace `schema` with your actual schema in the query string

```
Sub SendQuery()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs1 As Object
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim val, server_name, database_name, user_id, password As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    val = Trim(CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value))

    ' fill these out below
    server_name = ""
    database_name = ""
    user_id = ""
    password = ""

    ' connect to database
    conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
        & ";SERVER=" & server_name _
        & ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
        & ";UID=" & user_id _
        & ";PWD=" & password _
        & ";OPTION=3"

    ' setup select string
    sqlstr = "SELECT o.Name, o.OrganizationId FROM schema.Organization As o WHERE o.OrganizationId = '" & val & "' ORDER BY o.Name ASC"

    ' send query
    rs1.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic

    ' copy data to sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs1
    End With

    ' cleanup
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I've only had a chance to try this today. It's giving me the following error: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC Drive Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified